# Where can I find the Delphi unit Vcl.SysStyles for Delphi XE4?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, vcl-styles

I'm using Delphi XE4 with the latest code for vcl-styles-utils at https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-utils. I can not compile my app and getting the following error:

[dcc32 Fatal Error] Vcl.Styles.Utils.ScreenTips.pas(57): F1026 File not found: 'Vcl.SysStyles.dcu'

I can not find this unit anywhere. Where can I find the Delphi unit Vcl.SysStyles ?

Comment: It's most likely distributed with a more recent version of Delphi than XE4. It's in Berlin in the Delphi source\vcl and lib\winXX (32/64) tree. If it's not in yours, it's not in your version of Delphi. (And questions asking where to locate it aren't really appropriate here, as it would clearly fall under the category of an *off-site resource*, which is prohibited in the [help/on-topic] guidelines.)

Comment: My guess is that the missing unit was not present in XE4 and was added later. Probably @RRUZ's recent changes didn't test on older versions. Submit an issue on his github page.

Comment: Oh, it looks like you already did that. I think you need to wait.

Comment: Thanks guys for trying to help. I appreciate it. I did submit an issue for @RRUZ.

Answer (score 1):

Your diagnosis of the problem is incorrect. This is VCL unit which is supplied by Embarcadero with Delphi. This particular unit was added to the VCL after XE4, in 10.0 Seattle.

Therefore the problem is that vcl-styles-utils needs to include conditional code to suppress references to this unit for Delphi versions which pre-date its addition.

This issue has been fixed by a recent [commit](https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-utils/commit/95aeb35ee41f56abb5234187b740156eb7f939d0).